# unity's built in ik system is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

the built-in ik system for unity is not working at all for my custom character:
I have:

- a properly configured humanoid avatar
- enabled the ik pass in the animator's layer
- have a script calling onanimatorik() and setting the head ik in that function
- I am using a blend tree for animations

I have tried:

- messing with the mask of the animations inside the blend tree

Here is the code i use for the ik right now

```
[SerializeField]
protected Animator animator;
public Transform lookObj;
void OnAnimatorIK()
{
   animator.SetLookAtWeight(1);
   animator.SetLookAtPosition(lookObj.position);
}
```

Comment: here try provide some code that you have tried ,error logs or highlining any particular code problem ,    go through[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid downvote .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the controller script was on a parent object when it should have been on the object in question

thanks to milk_drinker01 on Discord for helping me

Comment: Please remove unnecessary details from your answer. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).